# Share folder & files from Ubuntu host to VM ware workstation mac os x lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, ubuntu-12.04, vmware-workstation

I am trying to share files from ubuntu host to the mac os x lion mounted in my VMware workstation 8. I have enabled file sharing in the vmware options settings. I have also enables file sharing in the mac os x. Still I cannot see any sign of mount or where to go and access the files available in ubuntu.

Detailed explanation of how to do it will be much appreciated :) Thanks.